# Education Gap With Work Experience

Tags: software-industry, recruitment, human-resources, education, employment-gaps

I have a confusion that actually my B.E Computer science Batch 2008-2012. but, since I backlog on one paper I did not complete my graduation on 2012 and joined in a small IT Firm.

I completed my degree on 2013. I am currently searching jobs in MNCs. Will there be any problem to consider my working experience from 2012 since I had backlogs.

Comment: "Will there be any problem" is not an answerable question. Please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/34914/edit) your question and make it something answerable like 'I plan to write this in my resume as ....... Is that clear?'

Comment: okay sir sure i will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will there be any problem to consider my working experience from 2012
>   since I had backlogs.

If you started working in 2012, then that's what you should indicate on your resume/CV.

And if you completed your education in 2013, then that's what you should indicate on your resume/CV.

Having overlapping work experience and graduation dates is very common, and is unlikely to cause any problems as you seek a new position. If it's ever questioned, just explain what happened. Try to come up with something better than just "I had backlogs".

Don't worry about it so much. This isn't at all unusual.

Comment: I would explain the situation in a cover letter.

Comment: I see you're point. It may be some thing to think about if you don't get an opportunity to explain yourself in an interview.

Comment: okay sir.. but it makes me worry sometimes thanks for the advise sir .